# ol.interaction.Draw: how to update style?

Tags: openlayers-3

How do I change the style of an existing `ol.interaction.Draw`? Is there a better way to do it than accessing the internal variable `(new ol.interaction.Draw()).overlay_.setStyle(…)`?

Answer (score 1):

When you set the style, set it to a function and then you're function can return a different style.  You could model it after this existing code:

```
ol.interaction.Draw.getDefaultStyleFunction = function() {
  var styles = ol.style.createDefaultEditingStyles();
  return function(feature, resolution) {
    return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
  };
};
```